# Confused about C#'s extension method overload resolution

Tags: c#, overloading, overload-resolution

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, long cnt)
    {
        return source;
    }
}

public class C 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        foreach(var e in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Take(5).ToArray())
            Console.Write(e + " ");
    }
}
```

I have an extension on `IEnumerable<T>` for `Take(long)`, which isn't provided by the framework. The framework only provides `Take(int)`. And since I'm calling it with an `int` parameter (`Take(5)`), I would have expected it to use the framework version, but it's calling my extension.

Am I missing something? The closest match would obviously be the one that takes `int` as a parameter, and `System.Linq` is included so it should be in the pool of valid overloads. In fact if I delete my extension, the correct framework function is called.

[For reference](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNMAfAAgJgIwCwAUFgAwAEWeAdADICWAdgI4DcxZleALO0RwGYuANko5yAUQAexAN7FyiykKqiqAgDwAVAHzktEANZxtOgBQwAFvShdNu8lAD2AVwQBjOEnIAbJ4wBzcndGGABKBSV5IiVYygB2R1cPOD5YgF9iTP4SFXEAYXI5SMVccRLyaLilADMnBDgId0szADcIBHI4ciZJRhcwRAhgHzhqACUIQLgzUm88UjDqA2MzAFYlrScAQQQECABPMzCImOq4/P9nUeoAdQR6eDNugGpyACIPsLSlbPSgA==)

Edit: Moving them to different namespaces shows the same problem:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace N1
{
    public static class Ex
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, long cnt)
        {
            return source;
        }
    }
}

namespace N2
{
    using N1;
    public class C 
    {
        public static void Main() 
        {
            foreach(var e in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Take(5).ToArray())
                Console.Write(e + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

[For reference](https://sharplab.io/#gist:3af31bc98c5fb687d71469a6c057622f)

Comment: From reading documentation on the `linq` `.Take`, you shouldn't ever need to pull more than 2 billion items from the `IEnumerable`. Hence, the reason the framework doesn't provide a `.Take(long)`.

Comment: Have you tried calling it with `5L` rather than `5` ?

Comment: I think because both your extension method and the caller are in the same namespace, that one wins. Can't remember the exact rules at the moment.

Comment: @Sean, I have no problem calling the `long` version of `Take`, that's in fact my issue.

Comment: @Blindy You're example has no real world application and would be considered poor design. Whether you asked for advice or not, I'm pointing out the fault in your example.

Comment: Once the extension method is inside the same namespace it uses it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That doesn't seem to be the case either, I moved both blocks to different namespaces, and imported the extension -- same result: https://sharplab.io/#gist:3af31bc98c5fb687d71469a6c057622f

Comment: Imagine you created that `Take` method before the other `Take` existed with your own logic and behaviour (like here behaving differently then the other `Take`) now suddenly a library also implements a `Take` extension but with an int, and suddenly when recompiling your own code is not called anymore since this new overload you might not know about has a "better" signature. Or atleast that is a scenario they're probably trying to prevent. Would very much feel like unexpected behaviour to me

Comment: @Blindy Most of the LINQ operations only support `int` for a reason, even when you get your overload working you will still struggle with other operations if your collection holds more than ~2 billion items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as Eric Lippert puts it:

> the fundamental rule by which one potential overload is judged to be
>   better than another for a given call site: closer is always better
>   than farther away.

[Closer is better](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/)

Comment: The last item on his list would apply to my second example, since the nested `using` is "closer" to my usage than the outside `System.Linq`. Indeed if I add `using System.Linq` in the nested namespace it works as expected. Weird, but I just asked for the reason, and you're right, it's this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.Linq.Enumerable.Take(source, 5)` instead of just `Take(source, 5)` to force using the original "Take" function or rename your own "Take" into somthing else "Takef" for example to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: It's an extension method, what you suggested makes no sense.

Comment: I've already got this problem, I don't know why but it helped (I know that in normal cases there is non sense to do this, but if it work... ^^'7)

Comment: You can call Extension methods as normal "Prefix" methods, instead of as "Infix" extension methods.   So `System.Linq.Enumerable.Take(someCollection,5);`